# Include single quote in only words regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I include single quotes when extracting words, so lets say I have a string like that:

```
s = "I won't go."
```

I want to run regex which gets me every word in this sentence, with keep won't as one words and not ['won', 't],
This is what I am working with:

```
words  = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z\-]+)", s)
Output: ['I', 'won', 't', 'go']
Wanted output: ['I', 'won't', 'go']
```

Any idea of how this could be achieved?

Comment: You could add the `'` to the character class or add a second optional part starting with `'` like `[a-zA-Z-]+(?:'[a-zA-Z-]+)?`

Comment: Why are you grouping by letters instead of splitting by whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import re

s = "I won't go."
words  = re.findall(r"([\w\']+)", s)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
s = "I won't go."
words  = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z\-']+)", s)
words
```